# PHP: Cut from string

Tags: php

$title = `' /home/nasann/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/bf4ff9b544.png';`

Need all words `"wp-content/uploads/2014/03/bf4ff9b544.png"`

Should return - `"wp-content/uploads/2014/03/bf4ff9b544.png"`

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Question -stop- Should at least show some effort -stop- Please show your attempts -stop-

Comment: I see you're using WordPress. What are you doing to get this image path? WordPress has built-in functions that will return the absolute path of an image.

Comment: @Carles Jove Buxeda iam use plygin not post type, how can do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [*explode*](https://www.php.net/explode),

```
$title = ' /home/nasann/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/bf4ff9b544.png';
$part = explode("/public_html/",$title); // wp-content/uploads/2014/03/bf4ff9b544.png
```

**[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/kWYfZh)**.

Comment: this also evaluates nicely in all PHP versions, [check it out here](http://3v4l.org/bBsQM)

Comment: @Rikesh
 
if i change nasann by any world , your code not work

Comment: its not work with me `<img src="<?="../".$part[1];?>" width="789px" height="auto" /> ` its get me  `<img src="<?="../" width="789px" height="auto" /> `

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
$resultStr=explode("public_html/",$title)[1];
```

it will give you the second element (index no. 1) of the splitted string: `{"/home/nasann/","wp-content/uploads/2014/03/bf4ff9b544.png"}`.

**ADDITION**:
based on this test, based on @webeno 's comment,
http://3v4l.org/hNiPP

this one is more reliable:

```
$resultStr=explode("public_html/",$title);
echo $resultStr[1];
```

Here is a demo: http://3v4l.org/m7V4r

Comment: @DHS Why do you think it's complex?

Comment: thank you for your kind advice, I have added an explanation, @DHS

Comment: the only backfall of this one is that it's giving an error in anything below PHP 5.4, see [this test](http://3v4l.org/hNiPP)

Comment: ...and therefore I'm passing on my upvote from this one to @Rikesh's answer...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `/home/nasann/public_html/` part is always the same, here is what you can do:

```
$title = '/home/nasann/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/bf4ff9b544.png';
$firstPart = strlen('/home/nasann/public_html/');
echo $output = substr($title, $firstPart);
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://3v4l.org/EQ2Id)**

Comment: if i change nasann by any world , your code not work

Comment: that's true, that's why I said at the beginning "Assuming the /home/nasann/public_html/ part is always the same..."

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regular expression. 
^ means that it matches in the start of the string.

```
$title = preg_replace('/^'.preg_quote(' /home/nasann/public_html/', '/') . '/', '', $title);
```